# Call a action method from a controller method in Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js

I want to call a action method with parameters from a controller in emberjs 1.8.
I can see examples of

```
this.send('actionMethd');
```

but no parameters are passed here. and not sure if it works with new ember js versions.

I can call controller method from action just like

```
this.controllerFunc(param1,param2);
```

doesn't seem to work the other way like this though

```
this.actionMethd(param1,param2);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
this.send('actionMethd', param1, param2);
```

See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_send